# PHP code returns bool(false)

Tags: php, api, curl

I have the following PHP code :

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

$url = "http://api/url/mac_address";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "msg=TEST");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

var_dump($output);

?>
```

It is working properly on one server, but when I run it on other server, it returns bool(false).

Comment: <?php

$ch = curl_init(); 

$url = "http://api/url/11:22:AA:44:55:22"; 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "msg=TEST");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

var_dump($output);
?>

Comment: One server can reach the url address, the other one cannot. As simple as that.

Comment: try to add the error output: if( $output === false) var_dump( curl_error($ch) );

Comment: Is one using a proxy & the other one not?

Comment: Can both servers ping the API's IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the next code to debug:

```
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: This helps me . There is a problem in domain resolving , considering that my 2 servers are located at different location, that's why code was working on one and on other wasn't. Tnx